# Trying to select element inside webelement, but i get object is not callable error

Tags: python, function, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to select element inside of web element, and i get: "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable"

```
def get_engagmet(driver, time, a):
    engagment = {}
    body_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_5pcr userContentWrapper']")
    link = body_element[a].find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@rel='theater']")
    print("this is link")
    print(link("href"))
    time.sleep(3)
```

By all accounts this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
print(link("href"))
```

with

```
print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

P.S. Also you might share the URL you are trying to scrape to check if your XPath matches correctly.